# android: listpreference setOnPreferenceClickListener error

Tags: java, android

```
Preference customPreference = (Preference) findPreference("customPreference");

customPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new onPreferenceClickListener)(){
     public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference){
          return false;
     }
});
```

I have problem with code above. I'm using eclipse and it keep suggesting me to setOnPreferenceChangeListener then when I changed per its suggestion, it instead suggest me to setOnPreferenceClickListener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `OnPreferenceClickListener` instead `onPreferenceClickListener`

```
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener;


customPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener(){
         public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference){
              return false;
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
customPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.onPreferenceClickListener)(){
     public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference){
          return false;
     }
});
```